# Is there a way for email alerts to be sent within Azure service fabric clusters

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, alerts

I understand there is way to monitor our clusters but if a node goes down then we won't know that it went down until we check on it ourselves. Is there a way that we can set up alerts to be emailed to us if something does happen withing the cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Azure Monitor, with that you can monitor and take action when some conditions happens in your case when a Cluster go down.
I hope that helps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-monitor/overview